# will a break statment break out of a while loop and an other if loop?

Tags: c, loops, break

I have a thread that logs serial data from a USB port. When the semaphore is posted and the variable `serial_logging_running` is `1` it proceeds to the `while(serial_logging_running == 1)` loop and continually reads the serial port and writs to file. When the program is exited the signal handler sets the variable `serial_logging_running` to `0`. Will the `break` statement exit the `while()` loop and the outside `if (res == 0)` and then proceed to return null statement?

```
static void *logging(void *param) {

    int rdlen, res;
    char ibuf[1024];

    sem_wait(&logging_semaphore); 

    /*Open log file and write to it from /dev/USB1*/
    create_open_log_file();
    res = log_dut_serial_data(serial_port);

    if (res) {
        fprintf(stderr,"Error opening the serial port%s\n",serial_port);
    }

    if (res == 0) {

        while(serial_logging_running == 1) {

            /*read from serial port write to log file*/
            rdlen = read(fd_joule, ibuf, sizeof(ibuf));

            if (rdlen > 0) {
                fwrite(ibuf, sizeof(char), rdlen, log_file);
                fflush(log_file);
            }

            if (rdlen < 0) {
                fprintf(stderr, "rdlen les than 0\r\n");
            }

            /* Exit the serial logging thread*/
            if (serial_logging_running == 0) {
                printf("Exiting serial logging thread\r\n");
                break;
            }


        }
    }

    close_serial_port_joule(); /*Exiting close the serial port*/

    return NULL;

}
```

Comment: what's an if-loop?

Comment: TLDR; Your approach is wrong. Asking this means that you have designed a bad algorithm. Rethink your algorithm and try again. This is just advice, you can try to force any kind of behavior your want but doing it the *right* way is always better.

Comment: Also, `break` is not needed here at all, because `if (serial_logging_running == 0)` then `while (serial_logging_running == 1)` will not enter the loop again.

Comment: Yes, `break` will break out the most inner loop. Can be read in every C text book.

Comment: There is no such thing as an if-loop.  If the question is about if `break` can get you out of multiple levels of loop, however, the answer is 'no'.  If you have nested loops and wish to break out of all of them (or any number greater than one), the cleanest solution is the much-maligned `goto`.

Comment: Sometimes it helps to split the algorithm into functions and use `return` instead of break. It removes any confusion like "how far out will this break statement take me?"

Answer (score 2):

> will a `break` statement break out of a while loop and an other `if` loop?

The `if` blocks are not relevant.  The `break` will "jump" to the end of the `while () { ... }` loop.

Yet in OP's case, the `break` will leave the `if (serial_logging_running == 0) { }` and jump to *almost* the end of the `if (res == 0) { }`.

```
if (res == 0) {
    while(serial_logging_running == 1) {
        ...
        if (serial_logging_running == 0) {
            ...
            break;  //  Jump to end of while loop
        }
    }
    // break "lands" here
}
```

> Will the `break` statement exit the `while()` loop and the outside `if (res == 0)` and then proceed to return null statement?

No.  Code flow will first proceed to end of the while loop.  Yet since the `if (res == 0)` has no more code, code flow will then complete that `if()`.  Then next code is `close_serial_port_joule();`, *then* `return NULL;`.

---

Also note the `break` here is not needed.  [@Iharob Al Asimi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47079808/will-a-break-statment-break-out-of-a-while-loop-and-an-other-if-loop/47080181#comment81108693_47079808)

Answer (score 1):

Understand the keyword `break`. It breaks out of the current last-initiated loop-block. An `if`-statement does not in any way generate a loop-block.

So yes, your program breaks out of the while loop at the `break`-statement and executes normally after that.

Answer (score 0):

**Break** breaks the loop caused by while. There is no loop to break with **if**. So yes, the **while** is "terminated" and the programs flow towards the **return NULL** -statement.